# HDD without drive letter, cannot assign either

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have just migrated from Ubuntu to Windows. I formatted and installed Windows on my SSD. But I had another HDD running for storage when I ran Ubuntu. Now with that drive connected as usual, it's not showing up in Windows. I appears in BIOS and in Disk Management, but without a drive letter. And the option to change the drive letter is grayed out (not available).

**Formatting and effectively erasing the drive isn't an option!**

What can I do? This is what it looks like:

[image: Disk Management]

Comment: What file system did it have?

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm not sure unfortunately. I have little experience in this matters.

Comment: That's the reason right there. If windows doesn't support the FS, then it can't use it.

Comment: @TheKB ok and how can I solve it? Is it impossible without data loss?

Comment: Without knowing the FS, it is hard to tell you.

Comment: @TheKB it's just not a matter of changing the filesystem with something like "MiniTools Partition Wizard" ?

Comment: That supports changing from NTFS to FAT16/32. All of these windows supports natively. If it was one of them, windows would recognize it.

Comment: You could also try something like [Extfs for Windows](http://www.paragon-drivers.com/extfs-windows/) by paragon to read the files off the disk.